# Android Google Play Movies app Play Video Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, netflix

I have a requirement to launch Google Play Movies app and start specific movie. I do have video/movie id's with me.

Please share information to start intent for this job.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I need information to start intent for Netflix and Hulu as well.

Comment: I got a clue to launch Google Play Movies app using package name like below but I could not open particular movie to play (using movie ID).            "startActivity(context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.videos"));"

Comment: Used "getLaunchIntentForPackage()" method for launching Hulu and Netflix but having problem to play a movie using movie ID.  Please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: check on developer site if there is any workaround

Comment: I did not find any workaround in developer site, please keep posted here if you find any fruitful solution.

Comment: Could you please update me here if any workaround available for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https://play.google.com/movies/movies?v=<video id>
sleep 1
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER
```